# In what way does Blindsight complement Truesight?

Tags: dnd-5e, special-senses

The [definitions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Senses) are quite clear,

Blindsight being:

> A monster with blindsight can perceive its surroundings without
>   relying on sight, within a specific radius.
>
> Creatures without eyes, such as grimlocks and gray oozes, typically
>   have this special sense, as do creatures with echolocation or
>   heightened senses, such as bats and true dragons.
>
> If a monster is naturally blind, it has a parenthetical note to this
>   effect, indicating that the radius of its blindsight defines the
>   maximum range of its perception.

and Truesight being:

> A monster with truesight can, out to a specific range, see in normal
>   and magical darkness, see invisible creatures and objects,
>   automatically detect visual illusions and succeed on saving throws
>   against them, and perceive the original form of a shapechanger or a
>   creature that is transformed by magic. Furthermore, the monster can
>   see into the Ethereal Plane within the same range.

While it's clear to see that these two are *not* the same, it's also interesting to note that Blindsight is written more of a mechanical suggestion while Truesight is more a list of dos and don'ts. This can prompt many comparative questions about blindsight, such as:

- Can a creature with Blindsight see in normal and magical darkness?
- Can a creature with Blindsight see invisible creatures and objects?
- Can a creature with Blindsight automatically detect visual illusions and succeed on saving throws against them?

and so on, going through the list of what Truesight or Detect Magic can do, but I wanted to focus on the mechanics of how each might be presented in-game and how they *compliment* one another instead. I am hoping that focusing on this side of the coin might bring some more insight to the table than a variation of "Truesight sees through magic, and Blindsight sees though your ears".

So: **In the mechanical terms of encountering an unknown monster who has either Blindsight or Truesight, how might the creature use his extra-special senses to mislead his enemy into thinking that they are gifted with the other kind of sight?**

This could be useful, say to cause a player to waste a spell slot on illusionary magic or miscast their Blindness/Deafness spell, as well as for newer players to better understand the mechanics of how each work.

Comment: I think the goal of this question is good and on topic. But I'm having trouble finding the actual question in the body. Are you looking for what does *Blindsight* do that *Truesight* can't and visa versa? Or if there is a benefit to having both? Please add your actual question to the body.

Comment: @linksassin Wouldn't those questions both have the same answer?

Comment: @Axoren Fundamentally yes but the structure would be different. But I'm not actually sure that either is exactly what the question is. Hence why I requested more clarity.

Comment: @linksassin I considered asking about the differences between the two, but I felt that would only repeat "Truesight is seeing through magic while Blindsight is using your ears and/or nose to see". So my hope was to ask about the similarities to envoke a more mechanical comparison between both types of senses. I will add this in question form.

Comment: When reading the question, the word "complement" implies that a creature has both Blindsight AND Trusight, is this intentional? If not, I recommend rephrasing. In common parlance, I would say analogously "In what ways does this Tie complement this Jacket?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Blindsight shows things as they are within range.

As per your examples:

- Blindsight allows the user to perceive within normal and magical darkness.
- Blindsight allows the user to perceive invisible creatures and objects.
- Blindsight could not detect visual illusions unless they have other senses those illusions affect. Visual illusions affect sight. This is an alternative sense.

  - Together with sight, the creature may still be fooled by an illusion simply because their senses do not agree with each other. No automatic success on the saving throw.

Things that True Sight does that Blindsight does not do:

- **Reveal the original form of a shapeshifter.** Shapeshifters who have changed their physical form would be perceived as that form.
- **See into the Ethereal Plane.** Common forms of Blindsight like the echolocation of bats cannot reach into the Ethereal Plane. There may be forms which would logically be able to see into the Ethereal Plane, such as ESP (not currently included in any published content). In general, a creature that can perceive the Ethereal Plane would have that singled out as its own feature.

Things that Blindsight does that True Sight does not do:

- **See around physical objects that do not block line of effect.** True Sight cannot see through objects. It instead shows those objects' true form. As a result, their true forms are *things blocking your vision* and True Sight doesn't help you see behind them. If something provides Total Cover to what's behind it from you, however this would be outside of line-of-effect.

Things that Blindsight might do that True Sight does not do:

- **See inside containers/enclosed areas.** Blindsight claims that it allows you to perceive in an area around you within a specific radius. It is not clear if this allows you to see through walls or into containers within range. For forms of Blindsight like Echolocation, it does not make sense to be able to see through walls if line-of-effect is cut-off within the area you can perceive. However, there may be other forms of Blindsight that give heightened senses which logically do breach these barriers, such as heightened smell smelling fresh food in a locked box. But those senses would normally be singled out as a separate feature.

Comment: Nicely said. I was confused at the third answer and slightly disagree, but I was simply going down the list of Truesight. While I agree that not being able to see a visual illusion disallows them to detect it was there (like a bat unable to see smoke), I would say that this is the reason why they WOULD automatically succeed on a saving throw against them. Since visual illusions, like hypnotic trance, don't include "visual and audio illusion", such as Magic Mouth, then they would automatically succeed on the saving throw as they cannot see the illusion.

Comment: @VictorB Succeeding against the illusion is meaningless to someone who can't see it in the first place. If someone has sight and blindsight, how does one know that the illusion isn't tricking their blindsight instead of their vision? Is something "invisible" to your blindsight or is it a "figment" to your sight? In the case of Hypnotic Pattern, your visual sense is being overloaded. You don't automatically save against it unless you close your eyes or have True Sight. Blind Sight doesn't protect your normal vision from being overloaded by an epileptic display of color.

Comment: Can you support your "See around physical objects" and "See inside..." with a reference? I can find no indication that Blindsight sees anything out of line of sight.

Comment: @Slagmoth Line of *Sight* affects *sight*, Blindsight is an alternate sense which says you perceive in a radius around yourself. The only thing that should affect it is line of *effect*.

Comment: "Sight" being what you can perceive as in sense in a manner akin to sight. Semantics aside though there is nothing in the definition of Blindsight to indicate that it goes around barriers or through them. Echolocation is a common example of method of blindsight in that case instead of light reflections it is sound but the premise is the same a bat can't see past nor around that wall. If you have a rules citation to support those claims please provide them otherwise you should make it more clear in the header of those it is merely speculation.

Comment: @Slagmoth I see there's a misunderstanding here. A wall providing cover blocks line of effect and that is not something Blindsight lets you see through. However, an object that does not block line of effect would not stop you from seeing what's behind it. I'll make my answer more clear.

Comment: Real echolocation would not be blocked by everything that blocks sight. Smoke is a given, but it should be able to see at least inside a tent or around a dressing screen, for example. In-game this is of course upnto the DM's interpretation.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir You're right in that Echolocation would get at least a lower quality read of things as their reflected sound bends around corners and edges, but for effects with and area, line-of-effect is measured in straight lines from the source. The only way to consolidate the reality of the kind of Blindsight with how it's simulated in game is to have the DM adjudicate.